# Javascript: can't access variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I can't access the variable from the marked point. The error console says the variable isn't declared. I've had the problem few years ago and I solved it, but I was googling for several hours and I can't find the solution anymore.
Do you have an idea, what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Thanks in advance.

```
var smileys = [
    [":smile:", "smile.png"],
    [":sad:", "sad.png"],
    [":love:", "love.png"],
    [":angry:", "angry.png"],
    [":amazed:", "amazed.png"],
    [":laugh:", "laugh.png"],
    [":wink:", "wink.png"],
    [":crying:", "crying.png"],
];

$(document).ready(function(){

    for(var i=0; i<smileys.length; i++){
        var smiley = document.createElement("img");
        smiley.src = "./res/" + smileys[i][1];
        smiley.style.width = "24px";
        smiley.style.height = "24px";
        smiley.onclick = function(){
            alert(smileys[i][0]);
            // $("#chat-input").append(smileys[i][0]);
        };

        $("#smileys").append(smiley);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you add the code around it? so we can see the scope of the variable

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/05ze77r8/ works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). Use `(function(i){smiley.onclick = function(){alert(smileys[i][0]);};})(i);` instead of your `smiley.onclick` line. Your problem is not that you can’t access `smileys`. Your variable `i` is an index outside the array when your `onclick` function gets executed.

Comment: @FastSnail Please take a look on my code. There is an "onclick" function. Within this function, I can't access the array.

Comment: @Reese can you show the console error too?

Comment: @ShlomiHaver
"TypeError: smileys[i] is undefined"

Comment: Of course you can access the array in your `onclick` function because the array is global. Your problem is the `I` being 8 which is out of range.

Comment: @RacilHilan Yes, that seemed to be the problem. Thank y'all.

Comment: If you couldn’t access `smileys`, you would’ve gotten `ReferenceError: smileys is not defined`. Precisely read the error: you’ve got a `TypeError` here. So all variables are found, but you’re trying to access a property of an undefined value, namely `smileys[i]`. And that’s because `i` is 8.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you provided, you can access the `smileys` array in your `onclick` function because the `smileys` is a global variable. Your problem is the `i` index of the loop being 8 in the `onclick` event which is out of range.

One good way to solve it is to save the value of the `i` in each `smiley` image and then access it inside the event like this:

```js
var smileys = [
  [":smile:", "smile.png"],
  [":sad:", "sad.png"],
  [":love:", "love.png"],
  [":angry:", "angry.png"],
  [":amazed:", "amazed.png"],
  [":laugh:", "laugh.png"],
  [":wink:", "wink.png"],
  [":crying:", "crying.png"],
];

$(document).ready(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < smileys.length; i++) {
    var smiley = document.createElement("img");
    smiley.src = "./res/" + smileys[i][1];
    smiley.style.width = "24px";
    smiley.style.height = "24px";
    smiley.value = i;

    smiley.onclick = function() {
      alert(smileys[this.value][0]);
    };

    $("#smileys").append(smiley);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="smileys"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same.

Comment: Hm… a closure in the loop or the `let` statement would be a better solution; storing an arbitrary attribute to an element (without using `data-` attributes) is a weird and instable workaround…

Comment: @Xufox You absolutely can use a `data-` attribute if you don't care to support old browsers. However, the `value` attribute works for all browsers. It is not an "arbitrary attribute", it is part of the HTML specs.

Comment: Yeah, but images don’t have a `value` attribute. It’s not a global attribute. Of course you can use `data-` attributes, that’s why I excluded them (“without using `data-` attributes”) from being a weird workaround.

Comment: @Xufox What I was trying to say is that the `data-` attributes are part of HTML 5, while "custom" attributes have been supported by all browsers for a long time now. Yes, `value` is not a global attribute, so if you add it to the image, it becomes a "custom attribute". If you want your code to be more modern, then I fully agree with you that using `data-` attributes is the way to go.